# How to choose a spesific object from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

We are making a simple rpg game. Right now we have a class called battleground, where the player can fight monsters. We use a random generator to pick out a random monster when we start the fight. In the terminal/main method, we have commands like "attack" and "run", that will either do damage to the random monster, or make the player leave/quit the game. Right now, we are trying to add a command called "attack scariest", which will let the player fight against the hardest monster with the most damage(there are three to choose from in our main). We need a method to choose a specific object from the ArrayList monsters, based on damage. Does anyone have tips on how we do that?

This is our code in the Battleground class that starts the game:

```
 public void startBattle() {
    printWelcomeMessage();
    boolean finished = false;


    this.currentMonster = getRandomMonster();


    if(this.currentMonster == null) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("A random monster is chosen for you. Prepare to meet the mighty " + this.currentMonster.getName());
    System.out.println("\n-------- Player Stats ---------");
    System.out.println(this.player);
    while(!finished && monsters.size() > 0) {
        ArrayList<String> commands = reader.getInput();

        if(isValidCommand(commands)) {

            if(commands.contains("quit") && !this.currentMonster.isDead()){
                System.out.println("You can't quit the game in the middle of a fight!");
            }else if(commands.contains("quit") && this.currentMonster.isDead()) {
                finished = true;
                System.out.println();
                printFinalStats();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("You have left the arena, and the game has ended.");
                System.out.println();
            }


            if(commands.contains("run")) {
                finished = true;
                System.out.println("You are a coward and you lose 50 gold pieces...\n");
                this.player.changeGold(-50);
                printFinalStats();
                System.out.println("\nThanks for playing...");

            }else if(commands.contains("drink") && !this.currentMonster.isDead()){
                Potion potion = (Potion) player.findItem(commands.get(1));
                player.drinkPotion(potion);

            }else if(commands.contains("equip") && !this.currentMonster.isDead()){
            Weapons weapon = (Weapons) player.findItem(commands.get(1));
            player.useWeapon(weapon);
            } else if(commands.contains("attack") && !this.currentMonster.isDead()) {

                if(this.player.attack(this.currentMonster)) {
                        playerWon();
                    if(this.monsters.size() > 0) {
                        System.out.println("\nThere are " + this.monsters.size() + " more monsters to beat\nType \"attack\" if you want to attack another monster, or \"quit\" if you want to end the game.");                 
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\n\n#### Congratulations ####\nYou have beaten every single monster in the game. You are a true champion!");
                        printFinalStats();
                        finished = true;
                    }

                } else if(this.currentMonster.attack(this.player)) {
                    printLosingMessage();
                    finished = true;
                }

            } else if(commands.contains("attack") && this.currentMonster.isDead() && this.monsters.size() > 0) {
                this.currentMonster = getRandomMonster();
                printContinueMessage(this.player, this.currentMonster);
                this.player.changeHealth(50);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Please write a valid command. Valid commands are:");
            printCommands();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ArrayList of monsters in the main class:

```
 Monster beelzebub = new Monster("Beelzebub", 60);
    Monster witch = new Monster("Witch", 40);
    Monster ogre = new Monster("Ogre", 80);

 ArrayList<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<>();

    monsters.add(beelzebub);
    monsters.add(witch);
    monsters.add(ogre);

  Battleground battleground = new Battleground(monsters, player, reader);
    battleground.startBattle();
```

We appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the ArrayList with a SortedSet or a PriorityQueue. Implement a Comparator for Monster class. Then just pick the first element of the monsters collection.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your Monster class but I'm assuming the second variable to the constructor is the 'damage level'? If not, ideally this should be something that belongs to each monster so you should be setting it somewhere.

So you have the array Monsters which has all the monsters with various levels of damage already. There are a lot of ways you could do this, but a simple way (given you only have 3 monsters) is to just iterate over your monsters and keep track of the monster with the highest damage, and then return that monster.

For example:

```
Monster findHardestMonster(ArrayList<Monster> monsters)
{
   //Set to the first monster in the list ASSUMING you have
   //at least one monster
   Monster highestDamageMonster = monsters.get(0);

   //Go through every monster in your array
   for (Monster monster : monsters)
   {
       //record the highest so far
       if(monster.getDamage() > highestDamageMonster.getDamage())
           highestDamageMonster = monster;
        }
    }

    //return it
    return highestDamageMonster;
}
```

If you plan on removing monsters frequently (say, when they're defeated), it might be worth as another poster suggested to use a priority queue or some sort of ordered collection whereby the ordering is based on damage level instead. Then you won't have to iterate over the monsters every time to find the one with max damage.

Comment: Post some code.. what part is specifically failing?

Comment: we got it working! thank you very much, you saved us <3

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<monsters.size()-1;i++){
        Monster m=monsters.get(i);
        Monster m2=monsters.get(i+1); 
        if(m.getDamage()<m2.getDamage()){
            Monster rightMonster=m2;
        }else{
            Monster rightMonster=m;
        }
    }
```

This should work if i am not mistaken. i havent tried the code but maybe it gives you hints

Answer (score 0):

The stream operations you can perform on the list will let you do this easily, by using `max` with a `Comparator` that ranks the monsters according to damage.

```
Comparator<Monster> orderByDamage = 
               (m1, m2) -> m1.getDamage() < m2.getDamage() ? -1
                           : m1.getDamage() == m2.getDamage() ? 0 : 1;
```

What this does is compare the damage of two monsters (`m1` and `m2`).  If the damage of `m1` is less than that of `m2`, a negative number is returned.  If they are equal, zero is returned and if `m1` has more damage than `m2`, a positive number is returned.

Note: if `getDamage()` returns an `Integer` and not an `int`, replace `m1.getDamage() == m2.getDamage()` with `Objects.equals(m1.getDamage(), m2.getDamage())`.

Use this with your list to get the monster with the most damage:

```
Optional<Monster> scariest = monsters.stream().max(orderByDamage);
```

Note the return type, which is `Optional<Monster>`.  If the list is not empty, the `Optional` will contain the scariest monster; if the list is empty, the optional will be empty - this will help avoid a `NullPointerException` if all monsters have been removed.

```
scariest.ifPresent(monster -> /* do something to the monster */);
```

You can also use this approach to get the monster with the least damage:

```
Optional<Monster> leastScary = monsters.stream().min(orderByDamage);
```